# Where to find Domino agent deletion log

Tags: lotus-domino

If an agent is deleted using Domino, where is the internal log maintained regarding deletion of that agent. Is it in log.nsf?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no log for deleted design elements. Why are you asking?

Comment: Ok this was just to confirm if some agent got accidentally deleted , if at all there is some log being maintained. I saw that if we cut an agent, and try to close the application, it does not show the dialog yes/no/cancel. But thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, there's no log for deleted design elements.